# ExtJS 4.2.2 - Can I read an imported JSON file from a filefield without sending it to a url?

Tags: javascript, web, extjs

ExtJS novice here. I need a way to let a user access file explorer from the browser for javascript to read without sending the file off to a server. It seems that a filefield doesn't have a clear way to just access the file that was selected other than the file name. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) from File API.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
  var fileDisplayArea = document.getElementById('fileDisplayArea');

  fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
   var file = fileInput.files[0];
   var textType = /text.*/;

   if (file.type.match(textType)) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
     fileDisplayArea.innerText = reader.result;
    }

    reader.readAsText(file); 
   } else {
    fileDisplayArea.innerText = "File not supported!"
   }
  });
}
```

```css
html {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  background: #333;
}

#page-wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em auto;
  min-height: 300px;
  border-top: 5px solid #69c773;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

h1 {
 margin-top: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

#fileDisplayArea {
  margin-top: 2em;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-wrapper">

  <h1>Text File Reader</h1>
  <div>
   Select a text file: 
   <input type="file" id="fileInput">
  </div>
  <pre id="fileDisplayArea"><pre>

 </div>
```

Example get from [codepen](https://codepen.io/matt-west/pen/KjEHg)